# Port does not nping in Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos7

I am trying to nping the port from my ubuntu machine which is open on centos 7 but it does not ping. Both my Machines are on same network. I also disable the firewall of centos 7 but it does not work. i also allow ports in firewall of centos 7.

**output of Centos 7 Machine**
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --list-ports
4000/tcp 80/tcp 4000/udp 80/udp

**output from ubuntu machine:**
sansforensics@siftworkstation:~$ nping -p 4000 192.168.100.12

Starting Nping 0.6.40 ( http://nmap.org/nping ) at 2017-07-12 08:19 UTC
SENT (0.0018s) Starting TCP Handshake > 192.168.100.12:4000
RECV (0.0020s) Possible TCP RST received from 192.168.100.12:4000 --> Connection refused
SENT (1.0034s) Starting TCP Handshake > 192.168.100.12:4000
RECV (1.0037s) Possible TCP RST received from 192.168.100.12:4000 --> Connection refused
SENT (2.0056s) Starting TCP Handshake > 192.168.100.12:4000
RECV (2.0059s) Possible TCP RST received from 192.168.100.12:4000 --> Connection refused
SENT (3.0073s) Starting TCP Handshake > 192.168.100.12:4000
RECV (3.0077s) Possible TCP RST received from 192.168.100.12:4000 --> Connection refused

**output of netstat -tulpn**

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12578/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11332/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11159/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12375/master
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      11332/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      11159/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      12375/master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           548/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55736           0.0.0.0:*                           548/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6660            0.0.0.0:*                           22513/dhclient
udp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           12578/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           12578/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           22513/dhclient
udp6       0      0 :::20241                :::*                                22513/dhclient

**output of firewall-cmd --list-all**
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens33
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 4000/tcp 80/tcp 4000/udp 80/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:

Comment: Please provide output of `netstat -tulpn` and `firewall-cmd --list-all` for the CentOS machine.

Comment: @Andreas Rogge output of firewall-cmd --list-all is
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens33
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 4000/tcp 80/tcp 4000/udp 80/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:

Answer (score 0):

You're not running any service on 4000/tcp, thus the tcp stack returns "Connection refused" which is expected and desired behaviour in that situation.

You can start some kind of listening daemon on 4000/tcp. I usually use Ncat for things like that: `nc -k -l 4000`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In centos 7 netcat by default uses the tcp6 connection. So nc -kl4 4000. So,ubuntu manchine can connect to the centos machine.